# How do i fix this? Since i added a table, which i forgot to add foreign keys on it. Now i want to modify it to fix the problem, but somehow it wont

Tags: mysql

**-- i added some attributes on my table "Professor"**

```
alter table Professor
add (
ClassroomID int,
SchoolID int,
DepartmentID int
);
```

**-- now i want to fix them but on references part has error on it. which this is my code down below**
-- error says  "***references is not valid at this position, expecting identifier***"

```
alter table professor 
add constraint foreign key (
ClassroomID, 
SchoolID, 
DepartmentID,
REFERENCES Classroom (ClassroomID),
School (SchoolID), 
Department (DepartmentID)
);
```

```
alter table professor 
add constraint foreign key (ClassroomID) references Classroom (ClassroomID);

alter table professor 
add constraint foreign key (DepartmentID) references Department (DepartmentID);

alter table professor 
add constraint foreign key (SchoolID) references School (SchoolID);
```

-- ***i tried doing it manually it works, but i wanted to fix it on one alter table***

Answer (score 1):

You can comma separate the `add` clauses, and you don't need the `constraint` keyword as you aren't explicitly naming the constraints.

```sql
alter table professor 
    add foreign key (ClassroomID) references Classroom (ClassroomID),
    add foreign key (DepartmentID) references Department (DepartmentID),
    add foreign key (SchoolID) references School (SchoolID);
```